# why find is recursively listing .log files even though the search pattern is not quoted

Tags: find, recursive

The find command I am using is recursively listing all the .log files even though the matching pattern is not quoted. As far as I know, if the search pattern is not quoted, it will be expanded by the shell, then find command will work on it,which should give the .log files only in the current directory.

> find . -iname *.log

Answer (score 2):

You're probably using one of those shells like `bash` and most other POSIX shells that don't report an error when globs don't match any file and instead pass the glob verbatim (unexpanded) to the application (and there happens not to be non-hidden files with a `.log` extension in the current directory).

In those shells, you'll find that

```
echo *.log
```

outputs

```
*.log
```

instead of an error like:

```
zsh: no matches found: *.log`

fish: No matches for wildcard '*.log'. See `help expand`.
echo *.log

echo: No match.
```

So if there's no `.log` file in the current directory:

```
find . -name *.log
```

Would be the same as

```
find . -name '*.log'
```

where a litteral `*.log` argument is passed to `find`.

Shells where that has been fix are `zsh`, `csh`, `tcsh` and recent versions of `fish` (well, in effect it was OK in earlier versions of Unix, but was broken in the Bourne shell in the late 70s and then fixed again in some shells). With `bash`, you can use `shopt -s failglob` to get the better behaviour.

Note that if there was one `.log` file in the current directory (like `file.log`, it would become:

```
find . -name file.log
```

And if there was more than one (like `file1.log` and `file2.log`), that would become:

```
find . -name file1.log file2.log
```

Which would be an invalid `find` invocation.

Answer (score -1):

What can be expanded by the shell is the *starting-point*, in your case `.` but not the search pattern.
So works as designed.

The command as follows would do the shell expand.

```
find *log
```

This command itself does not make much sense as you also could use

```
ls -1 *log
```

#### Update

As you mentioned in the comments below, your shell is taking care of quoting the search pattern.
And you are right that the search pattern will be expanded by the shell, but that normally will result in an error, which is described in the man page of `find` in the `NON-BUGS` section.

Comment: but *.log should also be expanded by the shell since it is not quoted.

Comment: I got the verbose output of the above find command I am using .. turns out the shell is explicitly quoting the matching pattern before submitting it to find. Below is the verbose output of the command:
pankaj@pankaj-Inspiron-7560:/$ find . -iname *.log
+ find . -iname '*.log'